# How to pass editText data to a string URL

Tags: android, json, url, android-edittext, uri

I Want to make a url in one of my activities(UploadActivity.java) by taking information from 3 edit text boxes in another activity (LoginActivity.java) and passing that data into the other activity,

All the questions i found here on SO only prtains to a static URL i.e. **www.blahblah.com/blah-blah.asp?My=Yes** etc.

basicly the user must input his email, password and client ID(made by my company) and then it must be consolidated into a string

like this one
       public static final String UPLOAD_URL = 
      "**https://www.smartpractice.co.za/files-upload-ruben.asp?clientID=6868**";

I'm using above url to  upload user's location to the server.

Must I declare the edittext boxes in the activity? because at the moment it is only i the XML layout of the activity

I found this in another question and I don't understand how to implement it into my code.

Your edit text

```
EditText your_edit_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_id);
```

Get user data from edit text as fallows ..

```
String edit_text_data = your_edit_text.getText().toString();
```

Now when you need to put that data on url .. use this like ..

```
String your_url = "http://www.google.com=" + edit_text_data;
```

**I want the Url here in this String in the "" quotations**

```
   public static final String UPLOAD_URL = 
  "https://www.smartpractice.co.za/files-upload-ruben.asp?MyForm=Yes";
```

**UploadActivity JAVA**

```
public class UploadActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "https://www.smartpractice.co.za/files-upload-ruben.asp?MyForm=Yes";
public static final String UPLOAD_KEY = "image";

private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

private Button buttonChoose;
private Button buttonUpload;

private ImageView imageView;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private Uri filePath;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);

        init();
        }
        private void init(){
        buttonChoose = findViewById(R.id.btnChoose);
        buttonUpload = findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
        }

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        }

public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        }

private void uploadImage(){
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Bitmap,Void,String> {
    private ProgressDialog loading;
    private RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        loading = ProgressDialog.show(UploadActivity.this, "Uploading Image", "Please wait...",true,true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        loading.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api=Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
        Bitmap bitmap = params[0];
        String uploadImage = getStringImage(bitmap);

        HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put(UPLOAD_KEY, uploadImage);
        data.put("name",getFileName(filePath));

        return rh.postRequest(UPLOAD_URL,data);
    }
}

    UploadImage ui = new UploadImage();
        ui.execute(bitmap);
                }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == buttonChoose) {
        showFileChooser();
        }
        if(v == buttonUpload){
        if(filePath!=null) {
        uploadImage();
        } else {
        Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this,"Select Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        }
        }
@RequiresApi(api=Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    String getFileName(Uri uri){
            String result = null;
            if (Objects.equals(uri.getScheme(), "content")) {
            try (Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null)) {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            result=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
            }
            }
            }
            if (result == null) {
            result = uri.getPath();
            assert result != null;
            int cut = result.lastIndexOf('/');
            if (cut != -1) {
            result = result.substring(cut + 1);
            }
            }
            return result;
            }
    }
```

**LoginActivity 
the edit text boxes are in the XML layout so far **

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }

}
```

In short Take editText values from `LoginActivity` and pass it to `UploadActivity` and use that information to build a URL in `UploadActivity`.

Comment: where is your login code?

Comment: better use something better than async task like okhttp or retrofit.

Comment: @AliAhsan The "login" is not really a login sorry, we are only rolling the app out to certain clients of my company so authentication is not really nescasary it is just there to save and load the email password and client ID wich i do not know how to do and am busy searching for that Also Note that I have only started coding and this basic android development about about a week ago so I am still pretty uninformed

Comment: @PembaTamang, why does it matter??

Comment: less boilerplate mate

Comment: @PembaTamang I have been coding(java) and learning android for about a week so I am still reall really new to this

Comment: use ohkttp it is easier
get started https://square.github.io/okhttp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Take edittext values from LoginActivity & Pass the values to `UploadActivity`

Bind your views in `onCreate` method in `LoginActivity` (change the ids with yours) & pass the input to `UploadActivity` through `Intent`.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText email,password,email;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

 email = findViewById(R.id.email); 
 password = findViewById(R.id.password);
 email = findViewById(R.id.clientID);
 Button loginBtn = findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);

loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String emailAddress = email.getText().toString().trim();
                String userPassword = password.getText().toString().trim();

             //Pass the data to next activity


             String clientId = clientID.getText().toString().trim();
             Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UploadActivity.class);
             intent.putExtra("clientId", clientId);
             intent.putExtra("email", emailAddress);
             intent.putExtra("password", userPassword);
             startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

> Use above information to build a URL in `UploadActivity`

```
    @RequiresApi(api=Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
            Bitmap bitmap = params[0];
            String uploadImage = getStringImage(bitmap);

            HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put(UPLOAD_KEY, uploadImage);
            data.put("name",getFileName(filePath));

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String clientId = intent.getStringExtra("clientId");

Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.scheme("https")
    .authority("ww.smartpractice.co.za")
    .appendPath("files-upload-ruben.asp")
    .appendQueryParameter("clientID", clientId);
String myUrl = builder.build().toString();

            return rh.postRequest(myUrl,data);
        }
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Thank you very much dude, will test the code out and let you know

Comment: Sorry just another plead for asistance    onResponse(Response response)
{
   String clientId = clientID.getText().toString().trim();
   Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UploadActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra("clientId", clientId);
   startActivity(intent);
}   Where must i put this.....also the rh on the post requst  of the webcall gives me cannot reolve symbol aswell as LOGIN_URL

Comment: I added `onResponse` code to give an idea but never mind I've updated the answer

Comment: if you find it helpful, please accept and upvote the answer. thanks